# How to launch a flutter page from native android notification click

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android

I have Intent Service in Native Android which I started from flutter using Channels.
Intent service is showing a local notification. If user click on the notification then I want to open
a flutter page. I am new in flutter I don't know how to achieve this scenario.
Please help me. If any sample code available plz share the link.
Thank You

Comment: Check https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this is url launcher but my requirement is launching specific flutter screen from native android code.

Comment: [How do I handle incoming intents from external applications in Flutter?](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter)